# Coldfusion ReReplace phone number reformat

Tags: regex, string, coldfusion

I'm trying to reformat a directory of phone numbers from a .pdf file. 
I extracted all of the text, and all of the phone numbers are in this format `( 555 ) 555 - 555`
I want to put them in this `5555555555`, followed by a `<br>`
I thought to do 
`#ReReplace(Directory, "\(.*?.\).*?.\-.*?", "", "all")#` but it left the spaces and I cant get the `<br>` in.
Am I on the wrong track?

Is it possible to use Rematch to return an array that splits the string up like

```
["some string ( 555 ) 555 - 555", "some string ( 555 ) 555 - 555", "some string ( 555 ) 555 - 555"]
```

Comment: They also have some other information, i.e. names. I want to reformat the phone numbers but keep the names attached(hence the line break)

Comment: Yes, I realized the text contained more than a single number after posting, so my suggestion would not work.

Comment: if the phone numbers are substrings of larger string, you have to do it in 2 steps. It requires a callback mechanism. If that's not possible, have to do it some other way. Anyway, match with `\([ \d]*\d+[ ]*\)[ \d]*\d+[ ]*-[ \d]*\d+` then in the callback, remove all parenthesis, dash, spaces `[() -]+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was kind of hoping that someone would have a better solution but

You can do this to load the matches into the array, suffix it with a value (I chose "ENDPN") and use a lookahead with ReMatch to check for the suffix, that way it won't pick up a random 10 digit string. CF (at least up to 10) does not natively support lookbehinds, but it does support lookaheads. You can invoke Java to do this, but it's really not necessary here.

Lookaheads allow you to assert that a pattern is after the expression (looking ahead), without capturing it. Lookbehinds allow to check prior to the string, in languages, such as Java, that support it.

If there's no danger of other 10 digit strings, all this is unnecessary.

```
<cfset Directory = '["some string ( 555 ) 555 - 5768", "some string ( 555 ) 555 - 1234", "some string ( 555 ) 555 - 0101"]'>

<cfset ParseNums = ReReplace(Directory, "\(\s*(\d{3})\s*\)\s*(\d{3})\s*-\s*(\d{4})", "\1\2\3ENDPN", "all")>

<cfset ArrNums = ReMatch("\d{10}(?=ENDPN)",ParseNums)>

<cfdump var="#ArrNums#">
```

If you still want the `<br />` inside the capture.

```
<cfset Directory = '["some string ( 555 ) 555 - 5768", "some string ( 555 ) 555 - 1234", "some string ( 555 ) 555 - 0101"]'>

<cfset ParseNums = ReReplace(Directory, "\(\s*(\d{3})\s*\)\s*(\d{3})\s*-\s*(\d{4})", "\1\2\3<br />ENDPN", "all")>

<cfset ArrNums = ReMatch("\d{10}<br \/>(?=ENDPN)",ParseNums)>

<cfdump var="#ArrNums#">
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this - using capture groups and backreferences we can extract the number out

```
#ReReplace(Directory, "\(\s*(\d+)\s*\)\s*(\d+)\s*-\s*(\d+)", "\1\2\3<br>", "all")#
```

Comment: Yep. I was about to suggest something similar, with (\d{3}) and (\d{4}) instead of (\d+) :) Side, note for readability you might want to use `\s`, instead of literal space characters. White space is easy for the human eye to overlook.

Comment: Good idea, I've edited it to use `\s`. I suppose phone number formats don't really change so `\d{3}` could work better

Comment: Well, my aim was just to ensure it did not match some weird edge case with less than the expected number of digits for a U.S. phone number :) (Though given the question description, it may be overkill).